Azure Event Grid Graph API SharePoint Event info useful?
Maybe I'm missing something here but I have a partner topic created that captures when a SharePoint list item is created. It then triggers my logic app; however, I don't really see any useful info from the event. Here's what I see:
  "body": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Graph.ListItemUpdated",
        "specversion": "1.0",
        "source": "/tenants/XXX/applications/XXX",
        "subject": "/sites/XXX/lists/EventGridTriggerTest",
        "id": "XXX",
        "time": "2024-10-22T21:28:52.3672838Z",
        "datacontenttype": "application/json",
        "data": {
            "subscriptionId": "XXX",
            "clientState": "",
            "resource": "/sites/SITEID/lists/EventGridTriggerTest",
            "tenantId": "TENANTID",
            "resourceData": {
                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.ListItem"
            },
            "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2024-11-29T19:40:37.891+00:00",
            "changeType": "updated"

So, it tells me the list name but nothing else. Shouldn't it at least send the list item ID? What am I missing?


Azure Event Grid Graph API SharePoint Event, it tells me the list name but nothing else. Shouldn't it at least send the list item ID?

Yes, It just gives the name and event id and other details of event. This is how the response of the api which cannot be changed.

captures when a SharePoint list item is created.

You can  use SharePoint Connector Triggers:

Click on SharePoint:


You can trigger for item and for files too.
Output:



Even this has a limitation that one need to provide the list name in the trigger.

And just to clarify, Event Grid does not capture the list item ID, correct? That would be helpful because then I could actually perform an action on the SP item

No, it does not.
